# Why is this type annotation wrong?

Tags: haskell, types, category-theory, isomorphism, higher-rank-types

I tried to follow the [article by Gabriel Gonzalez](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/gadts.html) and I ran into a type mismatch. Consider the following short module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

module Yoneda where

newtype F a = F a deriving (Show, Functor)

type G f a = forall a'. (a -> a') -> f a'

fw :: Functor f => G f a -> f a
fw x = x id

bw :: Functor f => f a -> G f a
bw x = \f -> fmap f x
```

It compiles fine. *(With either `ghc` 8.2.2 and 8.4.3.)* But when I poke it in repl, `fw` and `bw` do not compose:

```
λ :t bw . fw

<interactive>:1:6: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘G f a1’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the inferred type of it :: Functor f => a -> (a1 -> a') -> f a'
        at <interactive>:1:1
      Expected type: a -> f a1
        Actual type: G f a1 -> f a1
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘fw’
      In the expression: bw . fw
```

When I look at `bw` more closely, it appears that the types of the functor it takes and returns are distinct:

```
λ :t bw
bw :: Functor f1 => f2 a1 -> (a2 -> a') -> f1 a'
```

— Even though I stated in the type signature that they should be the same! And whatever type annotations I pepper `fw` and `bw` with, they do not want to unify.

If I remove the type signature from `fw`, everything works smoothly. In particular, the inferred type signature would then be:

```
fw :: ((a -> a) -> t) -> t
```

So, it appears that the `forall` quantifier spoils things. But I do not understand why. Should not it mean *"any type `a -> a'` will do, including `a -> a`"*? It seems as though the same type synonym `G f a` acts in different ways in the type signatures of `fw` and `bw`!

What's going on here?

---

Some more experiments:

```
λ (fw . bw) (F 1)
...error...
λ (fw (bw (F 1)))
F 1
λ :t fw . undefined
...error...
λ :t undefined . fw
...error
λ :t bw . undefined
bw . undefined :: Functor f => a1 -> (a2 -> a') -> f a'
λ :t undefined . bw
undefined . bw :: Functor f => f a -> c
```

So *(as @chi pointed out in an answer)* no function may be composed with `fw`. But not so for `bw`. Why?

Comment: This looks like a (bad) bug to me.

Comment: :type is not very accurate, especially for functions. Perhaps there is a bug that is messing up bw’s signature. Try using :type +v bw.

Comment: I get `bw :: Functor f => f a -> (a -> a') -> f a'`. How did you get `f1` and `f2` above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a predicativity issue.

Essentially, if we have a polymorphic value `f :: forall a . SomeTypeDependingOn a`, and we use it in some larger expression, this can instantiate the type `a` to any type `T` needed to fit that context. However, predicativity requires that `T` does not contain `forall`s.
This restriction is needed to have type inference.

In your code, `bw . fw` you use the polymorphic function `.` (composition). This has a polymorphic type, where one type variable `t` stands for the domain of the second function to be composed (`g` in `f . g`) . For `bw . fw` to type check we should pick `t ~ G f a`, but `G f a = (forall a' . ...)` so it violates predicativity.

The usual solution is to use a `newtype` wrapper

```
newtype G f a = G { unG :: forall a'. (a -> a') -> f a' }
```

which "hides" the `forall` under a constructor, so that `t ~ G f a` becomes allowed. 
To use that, one needs to exploit the isomorphisms `G` and `unG` as needed, wrapping and unwrapping as needed. This requires extra work by the programmer, but it is this work that enables the inference algorithm to do its job.

Alternatively, don't use `.`, and compose your functions in pointful style

```
test :: Functor f => G f a -> G f a
test x = bw (fw x)
```

---

About the type of `bw`, as reported by GHCi:

```
> :t bw
bw :: Functor f1 => f2 a1 -> (a2 -> a') -> f1 a'
```

This type is the result of "`forall` hoisting", which essentially "moves" the universal quantifiers in this way:

```
a1 -> ... -> forall b. F b   =====>     forall b. a1 -> ... -> F b
```

Hoisting is automatically performed so to help type inference.

More in defail, we have

```
bw :: forall f a . Functor f => f a -> G f a
-- by definition of G
bw :: forall f a . Functor f => f a -> (forall a'. (a -> a') -> f a')
-- after hoisting
bw :: forall f a a'. Functor f => f a -> (a -> a') -> f a'
```

Since now all the quantifiers are at the top level, when composing `bw` with another function as in `bw . h` or `h . bw`, we can first instantiate `f, a, a'` to fresh type variables, and then perform unification on such variables so to match the type of `h`.

For instance, in `bw . undefined` we proceed as follows

```
 -- fresh variables for (.)
 (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
 -- fresh variables for bw
 bw :: Functor f . f a1 -> (a1 -> a') -> f a'
 -- fresh variables for undefined
 undefined :: a2

 So we get:
 b = f a1
 c = (a1 -> a') -> f a'
 a2 = a -> b

 Hence the type of (bw . undefined) is
 a -> c
 = a -> (a1 -> a') -> f a'
 (assuming Functor f)
```

GHCi agrees, except that it chooses different names for the type variables. This choice is immaterial, of course.

```
(bw . undefined) :: Functor f => a1 -> (a2 -> a') -> f a'
```

---

Ah-ha! There seems to be some issue with GHCi-8.2.2 which is not present in GHC 8.4.3.

```
-- GHCi 8.2.2
> :set -XRankNTypes
> type G f a = forall a'. (a -> a') -> f a'
> bw :: Functor f => f a -> G f a ; bw x = \f -> fmap f x
> :t bw
bw :: Functor f1 => f2 a1 -> (a2 -> a') -> f1 a'

-- GHCi 8.4.3
> :set -XRankNTypes
> type G f a = forall a'. (a -> a') -> f a'
> bw :: Functor f => f a -> G f a ; bw x = \f -> fmap f x
> :t bw
bw :: Functor f => f a -> (a -> a') -> f a'
```

Comment: Thank you. I ran some more experiments and confirmed that indeed problems begin with `.`. However, it does not seem to be a problem for `fw`, even though its type also has `G`.

Comment: To me, this does not explain the type signature given to `bw` before composition is considered. Why does `bw`'s type mention an unrestricted, unrelated type `f2`? Not even GHC seems to believe the type is unrelated -- if you apply `bw` to a value that unifies with `f2 a`, GHC will also set `f1` to be the same thing!

Comment: @DanielWagner I can't reproduce `f2`. Maybe the OP is using another definition, where `G` quantifies `f` as well?

Comment: @chi I can, in 8.2.2 (the only version I have, so perhaps other versions do not have this bug).

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah, that's it, I think. See my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

The `forall` quantifier makes your type accept all `a -> a'`, but what your actually need in `fw` is a restriction ensuring that the parameter type and the returned type is the same, and that is what signature `a -> a` means.

So yes, the `forall` version accepts a function `a -> a`, but it accepts not only such functions. As stated above, the compiler tells you that `fw` should only accept a function with type `a -> a`.